# Cannot update FEZ Hydra firmware: Device is not connected or not responding

Tags: .net-micro-framework

**Update 1:**

Hi friends, could you please recommend me a powered USB hub in Australia(preferred in Melbourne)? I guess my problem is caused by the insufficient power supply.

---

Hi friends,

I have a FEZ Hydra Basic kit. I got it in 2012 (might be in Sep). 
Today I downloaded the latest SDKs, drivers and everything(NETMF and Gadgeteer Package 2014 R1). (.NET Micro Framework 4.3 and the firmware I have on my laptop is 4.2.6.2)

But the firmware on my deivce is 4.1.x.x(I was lucky to saw the device's firmware version just once and I followed the instruction on the software FEZ Config, but failed with errors).
After that, I cannot get the Device's firmware version any more.

I found changing USB ports sometimes help. I have 4 USB ports, some of them can connected to the device, others are not.

So I have no idea to update the firmware in other way.

Could someone please help me to figure out how to find a way to update my firmware?

[image]

In the attached image, it shows: the FEZ Config detected the FEZ Hydra and was trying to get the device's firmware version, but it failed to do so and followed by an error message say: Failure - Device is not connected or not responding.

As I mentioned above, I was lucky to see the FEZ Config successfully got the device's version only once.

So my guess is - is it because the output power is not strong enough to support the operation, so I have to use something like a USB hub which has a strong and stable power?(I saw someone mentioned this and cannot find the comments any more).

Bt the way, all USB ports I mentioned above are directly on my laptop which means they get power directly from motherboard, so they should have strong and stable power to support my operations.

I have been stuck at this issue for the whole day, I really hope some friends can help me out.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've had like the same issue. While updating the firmware it threw me that message and I could not reach my Gadgeteer *Fez Hydra at all. I managed to solve it by attaching an external power supply to it. I use the USB Client DP (Dual Power) 1.3. This way you do need the power over USB part and you can safely update the firmware.

USB Client: https://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/280

edit: If that doesn't solve your isse you might want to reset the Loader first. Which is given as a tip on the GHI website before updating the firmware.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @ILoveCoding: Why is this not answering the question? The OP just needs a stable power supply and only connecting via USB is not providing him that. It might maybe not help him specifically but it's at least something to try.